# Nice hover effect in css3

Tags: css, hover, border, effect

I was trying to do some hover effects like on nvidia page ( http://www.nvidia.com/object/cool_stuff.html ) in css3, the result is here http://www.html5.ssl2.pl/ . Now as you can see it doesn't work well - when you will hover one div, all others will move and there is also a problem with border (giving more space)

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{
background: #eee;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

div.nowy{
position:absolute;
width:200px;
height:100px;
background:grey;
border: 0px solid #eee;
-moz-transition: border 0.2s, box-shadow 0.2s;
-webkit-transition: border 0.2s, box-shadow 0.2s;
 box-shadow: 1px 3px 3px black;
}

div.nowy:hover {
border:5px solid white;
box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px black;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div style="width:800px; height:300px; margin-top:50px; margin-left:50px; position:relative">
<div class="nowy" style="left:100px;"></div>
<div class="nowy" style="left:350px;"></div>
<div class="nowy" style="left:600px;"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Any idea how to fix that? 
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/t2UCW/2/

```
body{
    background: #eee;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position: relative;
}

div.nowy{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left:10px;
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background:grey;
    border: 0px solid grey;
    -moz-transition: border 0.5s, box-shadow 0.5s, top 0.5s, left 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: border 0.5s, box-shadow 0.5s, top 0.5s, left 0.5s;
     box-shadow: 1px 3px 3px black;
}

div.nowy:hover {
    border:5px solid white;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px black;
}

.d1, .d2, .d3 { top: 20px; }
.d1 { left: 50px; }
.d2 { left: 300px; }
.d3 { left: 550px; }

.d1:hover, .d2:hover, .d3:hover { top: 15px; }
.d1:hover { left: 45px; }
.d2:hover { left: 295px; }
.d3:hover { left: 545px; }
```

Comment: Wow this came out perfect. Personally I like it better then the original

Comment: @Amay I'm not sure if you're aware of this, but none of this will animate in any version of IE... You'd be better off using jQuery.

Comment: @StefanNch WOW! This Vanilla framework looks pretty cool! It seems pretty useful but it's interesting... when comparing it to JQuery they don't seem to show Animations? Or Cross Browser Compatibility? Plus it seems like you need to include a prototype, JUST to select by class? I understand JQuery is overused in a ton of cases, but not animation... I get it, being a purist is fun especially if your name is Stefan, and will work fine on the little blog you maintain, but most of us have a lot more work to do.

Comment: @MikeyG Oh!.. I didn't know that using javascript makes me a purist (aren't you the polite one?) or that I maintain a small little tiny blog. Good luck with your busy schedule that prevents you writing a cross-browser-compatible setInterval function. I've (sort of) noticed that you do have time posting on SO, on a two years old question. Life must be hard on you and I don't hit people lying on the ground!

Comment: @StefanNch Using a framework is the only time effective way to do any sort of real animation (other than CSS3 animation which isn't supported by everything yet). If you don't agree with that then you obviously haven't done any animation yourself. Why are you so against using JQuery for even small things? Plain javascript will always be more efficient, but these days efficiency isn't nearly as important as how intuitive it is for others to read and maintain your code. It's like telling someone to use C++ instead of Python for no good reason, and it's annoying.

Comment: @MikeyG I have used JQuery for more than one year. But something went wrong: 1. Enormous amount of time allocated to fix or workaround framework-specific issues. Never needed a SO like account pre-using frameworks, as documentation and blogs where enough. 2. "Gaps" created between the programmer and the actual language (talking about issues, doesn't make you aware of them). 3. The performance wall (the only way of fixing it is dropping everything). 4. No version is fully backward compatible with an older one. 5. No code has a general purpose (thus frameworks are full of ... good intentions).

Comment: @StefanNch That sucks man, maybe I'm lucky my experience was the opposite. I never really enjoyed js until I started using JQuery, and then everything just worked. Were you using JQuery 2?

Comment: No. I had to use 1.[something], because support for the dead IE6 was needed. JS for me was/is easy, because of my actionscript background. "Flex", "Django", "JQuery" you name it ... all are a bunch of time consuming monsters (not to mention php frameworks that makes me more confused than previous named frameworks put together). Regarding JQuery, yes is pretty and is quick to write code, but in time I've solved all the big crossbrowser issues with a handful of functions. Something like [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/). But only for my purposes. Not the whole web community. So far so good.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting their positions as absolute instead of relative.

Although the nvidia page you linked does this in flash you should still be able to achieve what you're doing in css3 with some jQuery maybe.

Comment: I fixed the position:relative and absolute. Now need help with border.

Comment: @Amay check out my answer. It looks like the position gets animated instantly tho, so it still looks slightly choppy. I haven't done enough animation with css3 to know why that is.

Comment: You can give it a left and top border of the same width as the hover effect with the same color as the background. That's the easiest way to fix this. There might be better/harder ways though

Comment: @Mikey G I will try that tomorrow. Roozbeh15 That was my first idea, but as u can see I added some box-shadow, so you can still see border even if u change the border to background color

Answer (score 1):

Here is a try without using absolute positioning: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/knvrS/)

Not quite right...

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to set their positions to **relative**, but you're also going to need to animate the position at the same time that you animate the border.

Because you are using border for animation, you're going to have to change the position at the same time in the opposite direction, so they will cancel out the movement of your border.

The reason they are getting out of line is because they are actually getting bigger and becoming farther away from where they were originally.

Try adding:

```
position: relative; 
right: 5px;
left: 5px;
```

to the `div.nowy:hover` class, or where ever you are doing the animation for the border.

Comment: Hmm... some example? :] Should I just use transition for 'left' ?